# How can I change the keyboard shortcut for "disable breakpoint" in VS2015?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

In Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, I can change shortcuts for a variety of operations, but I can't seem to find any option for "disable breakpoint", only "create breakpoint", "delete breakpoints", and "disable all breakpoints".

What I want is to make F9 disable rather than delete breakpoints.

Comment: Good odds that you are looking for the Debug.ToggleBreakpoint command.

Comment: No, Toggle Breakpoint creates or deletes a breakpoint. I want to enable/disable it, because sometimes I have breakpoints with conditions that I don't want to have to copy/paste every time I accidentally delete them meaning to disable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Debug.EnableBreakpoint** command works like a toggle and lets you disable the selected breakpoint.

Comment: Hmm, but it won't create a breakpoint if there's not already one there, so I still have to use a separate shortcut to create one. Still, I suppose you did answer my original question...

Answer (score 1):

For a single shortcut to create/disable a breakpoint, you can use the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        dte = DTE;
        if (IsCommandAvailable("Debug.EnableBreakpoint"))
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.EnableBreakpoint");
        else if (IsCommandAvailable("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint"))
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint");
    }

    private bool IsCommandAvailable(string commandName)
    {
        EnvDTE80.Commands2 commands = dte.Commands as EnvDTE80.Commands2;
        if (commands == null)
            return false;
        EnvDTE.Command command = commands.Item(commandName, 0);
        if (command == null)
            return false;
        return command.IsAvailable;
    }

    private EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
}
```